# Will using -static with GCC guarantee that my C programme will work across x86 distros?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, static-libraries, glibc

I'm using stdio.h , string.h , math.h in a simple math tool written in C.

I hear that -static in gcc does not actually always statically compile libraries (i hear this from Linux-pro jargon which i don't understand) and I also hear from the same sources that software development for Linux is a pain due to fragmentation and different distributions requiring re-compilation for each one.

Since i'm not doing a GUI or a custom library , or anything too complex, I hypothesise that i dont have to compile again for each distro and statically linking with -static in gcc while compiling on my Ubuntu 20.04 system will create an executable binary compatible with nearly all x86_64 Linux systems. Am I right ? Will it work across at least Debian, Ubuntu , Arch and their derivatives ?

I saw a video of Garry from Android Authority who statically compiled his C program he made on a Raspberry Pi and ran it on Android, so i'm guessing this is possible.

Comment: why does no body answer anymore

Comment: I don't know enough to answer properly but I would assume that even dynamically linked simple programs run on most not-too-ancient "normal" distros (anybody correct me?). I would be amazed if you ran into trouble with a statically linked program, even if it secretly pulls in some stuff at run time. Whatever it is, it must be commonplace.

Comment: Static linking is no guarantee of compatibility. Kernel access isn't standardized, library function calls are.  For example, you code might call POSIX `open()`, but the underlying kernel call may be implemented with the `openat()` call, for example, where earlier kernel versions did have an `open()` call. In that case, a normal dynamically-linked binary would work fine, but a statically-linked one would fail. And you haven't addressed what set of CPU instructions your executable uses...

Comment: Well, @AndrewHenle, all you say is right-- the bottom line: Neither a dynamically nor a statically linked program will run on all past, present or future distros. In a way, a dynamically linked libc provides a compatibility layer, and newer systems tend to have old libcs around exactly for that reason (the same Windows does).

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica Windows definitely does compatibility along these lines much better than Linux does. I should have mentioned the first order of business here is determining what Linux distribution(s) and their version(s) are going to be supported.  Then finding a solution that works for that set.  I'd also never try for *backwards* compatibility. If I had to support RHEL 6 and RHEL 7, for example, I'd compile on RHEL 6 - on a machine with an *old* CPU, maybe even a VM or QEMU instance to guarantee no new machine instructions get compiled in.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I'm trying to be able to support Ubuntu , Debian and Arch ... Also, this is a 32-bit x86 program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the headers you list, the only dependency on `dlopen` is implied by the mode argument of `fopen`: If the `,ccs=` parameter is used there, `fopen` will try to `dlopen` a gconv module, for character set conversion.

Apart from that, none of the functions declared in `<stdio.h>`, `<string.h>`, `<math.h>` will perform an implicit `dlopen`, so static linking should be safe in this particular case.

Comment: Thanks... The technical and detailed comments above from @AndrewHenle will have me believe that dynamic compilation is a better idea for compatibility. Is this indeed true , at least for non-obsolete versions of ubuntu, debian & arch ? PS : I'm compiling on Ubuntu.

Comment: Dynamic linking will increase compatibility, but you have to build against the oldest distribution you want to support.

Answer (score 1):

The glibc library still uses some dynamic features even when linked statically. That might work on older distributions, since things like NSS (name service switch) have been around a long time.

If you want to be really static, you should use uclibc or other similar tiny C libraries. But then, if the system used features to override DNS, user IDs (like looking up users in LDAP), home directory locations, etc, they won't work.

There's another problem then: kernel support. If you build your static library on a very new kernel, the library might have been built to use system calls from the new version, and those system calls might not exist if you go to an old enough distro. A kernel like 2.4, 2.6 or 3.X would definitely have missing system calls.

Comment: Out of curiosity, would a program calling a missing kernel routine simply crash?

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica No, I believe it will return ENOSYS as an error code.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica Except some libc wrappers return other codes like EPERM or EFAULT, which are bugs, but what can you do.

Comment: I'm compiling on the current mainline Ubuntu version of Linux , 4.something